# Настроить потоки в pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки `Stop`, потоки останавливали работу, и интерфейс не залипал, а после я мог нажать `Start`, чтобы потоки продолжили работать с места где остановились.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

"""Класс инициализирующий первый поток"""
class first_thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, mainwindow, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow

    def run(self):
        self.count = 0
        while self.count < 100:
            self.count += 1
            self.mainwindow.first_lcd.display(self.count)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)

"""Класс инициализирующий второй поток"""
class second_thread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, mainwindow, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainwindow = mainwindow

    def run(self):
        self.count = 0
        while self.count < 100:
            self.count += 1
            self.mainwindow.second_lcd.display(self.count)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(100)

"""Класс, который создает окно и распологает на нем виджеты"""
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        #Объявляем центральный виджет, на нем будут располагаться остальные
        self.resize(810, 310)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #Располагаем два LCD Number
        self.first_lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.first_lcd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 380, 80))
        self.second_lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.second_lcd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 70, 370, 80))
        #Распологаем кнопки start и stop 
        self.start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 240, 110, 50))
        self.start_btn.setText("Start")

        self.stop_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stop_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 240, 110, 50))
        self.stop_btn.setText("Stop")
        #Располагаем два текстовых указателя(label)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.first_thr_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.first_thr_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 160, 30))
        self.first_thr_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.first_thr_lbl.setText("Первый поток")

        self.second_thr_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.second_thr_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 20, 150, 30))
        self.second_thr_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.second_thr_lbl.setText("Второй поток")
        #Располагаем центральный виджет на окно
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        #Объявляем потоки
        self.first_thread = first_thread(mainwindow = self)
        self.second_thread = second_thread(mainwindow = self)

        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.launch_threads)#Кнопка подает сигнал в функцию, запускающую потоки
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_threads)#Кнопка подает сигнал в функцию, останавливающую потоки

    #Функция, запускающая потоки
    def launch_threads(self):
        self.first_thread.start()
        self.second_thread.start()
    #Функция, останавливающая потоки
    def stop_threads(self):
        self.first_thread.usleep()
        self.second_thread.usleep()

"""Запуск скрипта"""
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя использовать объекты основного потока в дополнительных потоках, это не безопасно!
Надо использовать сигналы и слоты, примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.Qt import *


"""Класс инициализирующий первый поток"""
class first_thread(QtCore.QThread):
    first_thread_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    first_thread_finish = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self): #, mainwindow, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
#        self.mainwindow = mainwindow
        self.count = 0
        self.flag = True

    def run(self):
#        self.count = 0
        while self.count < 100 and self.flag:
            self.count += 1
#            self.mainwindow.first_lcd.display(self.count)
            self.first_thread_signal.emit(self.count)
            self.msleep(100)
        self.first_thread_finish.emit()

"""Класс инициализирующий второй поток"""
class second_thread(QtCore.QThread):
    second_thread_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    second_thread_finish = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.count = 0
        self.flag = True

    def run(self):
        while self.count < 100 and self.flag:
            self.count += 1
            self.second_thread_signal.emit(self.count)
            self.msleep(100)
        self.second_thread_finish.emit()

"""Класс, который создает окно и распологает на нем виджеты"""
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()

        #Объявляем центральный виджет, на нем будут располагаться остальные
        self.resize(810, 310)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        #Располагаем два LCD Number
        self.first_lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.first_lcd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 70, 380, 80))
        self.second_lcd = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.second_lcd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(420, 70, 370, 80))

        #Распологаем кнопки start и stop 
        self.start_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.start_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 240, 110, 50))
        self.start_btn.setText("Start")

        self.stop_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stop_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 240, 110, 50))
        self.stop_btn.setText("Stop")
        #Располагаем два текстовых указателя(label)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.first_thr_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.first_thr_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 20, 160, 30))
        self.first_thr_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.first_thr_lbl.setText("Первый поток")

        self.second_thr_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.second_thr_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 20, 150, 30))
        self.second_thr_lbl.setFont(font)
        self.second_thr_lbl.setText("Второй поток")
        #Располагаем центральный виджет на окно
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        #Объявляем потоки
        self.first_thread = first_thread()   #(mainwindow = self)
        self.first_thread.first_thread_signal.connect(self.first_lcd_display)
        self.first_thread.first_thread_finish.connect(self.first_finish)

        self.second_thread = second_thread() #(mainwindow = self)
        self.second_thread.second_thread_signal.connect(self.second_lcd_display)
        self.first_thread.first_thread_finish.connect(self.second_finish)

        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.launch_threads)#Кнопка подает сигнал в функцию, запускающую потоки
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.stop_threads)#Кнопка подает сигнал в функцию, останавливающую потоки

    def first_lcd_display(self, value):
        self.first_lcd.display(value)

    def second_lcd_display(self, value):
        self.second_lcd.display(value)    

    def first_finish(self):
        if self.first_thread.count == 100: self.first_thread.count = 0

    def second_finish(self):
        if self.second_thread.count == 100: self.second_thread.count = 0 

    #Функция, запускающая потоки
    def launch_threads(self):
        self.first_thread.flag = True
        self.second_thread.flag = True 
        self.first_thread.start()
        self.second_thread.start()

    #Функция, останавливающая потоки
    def stop_threads(self):
        self.first_thread.flag = False
        self.second_thread.flag = False 
#        self.first_thread.usleep()
#        self.second_thread.usleep()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    """Запуск скрипта"""
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, вы второй раз выручаете меня :) После этого проекта подучу pyqt5  получше

Comment: @Максим  Механизм сигналов и слотов является центральной особенностью Qt и, вероятно, той частью, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими платформами. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html